# Bootstrap гамбургер меню при любой ширине экрана

Tags: css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Каким образом и где можно сохранить Bootstrap гамбургер меню(navbar) при любом разрешении экрана а не только `max-width: 767px`?

Answer (score 1):

Подключите свои стили после стилей `bootstrap`

```
<link href="путь/до/бутстрапа" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="путь/до/ваших/стилей" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Потом в желательно в конце ваших стилей добавьте медиазапрос т.е. так вместо 322 может быть любое число

```
@media screen and (max-height:322px) {
//тут пишите стили
}
```

Вот пример

```
@media screen and (max-height:322px) {
  .navbar {
     color:red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените @media для данного класса в своих стилях(должны быть последними при привязке к странице). Должно заработать, если я понял вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите на **Bootstrap 4**, то есть классы регулирующие отображение гамбургера **navbar-toggleable-***.
[Вот подробная статья на английском](https://bootbites.com/articles/change-bootstrap-4-navbar-collapse-navbar-toggleable-classes/)

---

Если **Bootstrap 3**, то ответы уже дали другие комментаторы